# How did Ancient Greek 'πυρ' become English 'fire?'

Tags: phonology, phonetics, greek, fricatives, plosives

*fire* is derived from the Ancient Greek *πυρ*. My question is: how did the plosive become a fricative?

I believe *pyre* is also derived from *πυρ*; why is it that *pyre* didn't also undergo this "fricativisation"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As jlawer says, English "fire" doesn't actually come from Greek *pŷr*. "Pyre" does, but that's a borrowing (via Latin), and it's pretty clear how it happened. Instead, English and Greek share a common ancestor (Proto-Indo-European), which split into Pre-Proto-Germanic and Proto-Hellenic (and many other branches) several thousand years ago.

One of the reconstructed Proto-Indo-European words for "fire" looked something like **peh₂-wr̥*. The **h₂* was probably a velar fricative, like in "lo**ch**", but there's not a strong consensus on that part. (Compare, as Arnaud Fouret suggests in the comments, the Hittite form *paḫḫur*.)

In Proto-Hellenic > Ancient Greek, the **eh₂w* in the middle simplified to give something like **pūr*; then the `/u/` fronted to `/y/`, and a bit of tone funkiness happened, giving *pŷr*.

In Germanic (the branch of Indo-European containing English), a process called "Grimm's Law" happened, which changed voiceless stops (p, t, k) at the beginning of words into fricatives (f, th, h).

The vowel in the middle went through some strangeness involving a collective form, but the branch that would become English eventually simplified it into something like **fuir*; the *ui* merged into *ȳ*, which English then turned into *ī*. Spelling conventions then turned *fīr* into *fire*, and the Great Vowel Shift gave it its modern pronunciation.

Comment: It can be added that Hittite has the word pahhur "fire", that bolsters the reconstruction *peh2-wr for the original proto-language.

Comment: @ArnaudFournet Good suggestions! Added a note

Comment: No, it's not "pretty clear how it happened", the pre-history is pretty much in the dark, except that a constructed language of reconstructions exists that is nowhere near complete nor really verifiable. It's testable, going backwards from one language to a reconstruction and back forward to a different language. Often the meaning of the word in the other language is only remotely related, or even opposite. Given the misconception in question, it might be helpful to mention the evidence that Germanic had sperated from a branch that could not be rightfully called Greek. AFAIK this isn't settled.

Comment: Of course it can't be rightfully called Greek, either, if the matter isn't settled. Don't get me wrong.

Comment: @vectory Sorry, but…what? The etymology I said was pretty clear was that of "pyre". We have attestations of every stage of the development from AGrk *πῦρ* to Latin *pȳra* to French *pyre* to English "pyre", with no reconstruction involved.

Comment: Oh, quotes out of context, right? Myrequest is still valid for *fire*.

Comment: @vectory What exactly is your request?

Comment: A good answer! Everything is crystal clear.

Comment: "*Given the misconception in question, it might be helpful to mention the evidence that Germanic had sperated from a branch that could not be rightfully called Greek. AFAIK this isn't settled*" If you missed this note, then I don't know why.

Comment: @vectory As in, specify that Germanic doesn't descend from Greek? I thought I already had, but sure

Comment: No, you basically said that ProtoIE dissolved at once into different branches. You implied at the same time, that Proto-Germanic, as well as whatever was before Greek, is supposed to have been a separate branch before any evidence of Greek. It's widely assumed that other families branched of earlier, yet you say PIE, as if the "core" continued PIE. In the same vein, whatever was continued by Greek could be called Greek at the lower nodes, if one felt so inclined. I'm asking for the evidence of your tendency, because the theoretical development is still speculative and necessarily inconsistent.

Answer (score 25):

English *fire* is not derived from Greek *πυρ*.

Both *fire* and *πυρ* come originally from the Proto-Indo-European root [**paəwr̥*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=pa%C9%99wr%CC%A5).

Greek simplified the **aəw* vowel sequence to /ū/, but kept the consonants.

Proto-Germanic was **fūr*, similar to Greek, but all Germanic voiceless stops like **p*
became homorganic fricatives like **f* as part of the group of consonant changes
known as "Grimm's Law".

Modern English *fire* comes from Old English *fȳr*, which was produced by fronting the Proto-Germanic  *ū* to *ȳ*, a natural process called "[Umlaut](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/77866/15299)", which is very common in Germanic languages.

Comment: Modern Dutch has "vuur", which sounds like OE fȳr (especially in the western Netherlands where initial v- is pronounced f- by most), and some conservative fronting dialects have "vier" (with [i:] sound).